# Can there still exist equilibrium with a very high equilibrium constant?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium

#### Problem

> Consider the reaction translated by:
>
> $$\ce{2 CO(g) + O2(g) <=> 2 CO2(g)} \quad  K_c = 2 \times 10^{22}~\text{at } \pu{1000 K}$$
>
> The order of magnitude of the equilibrium constant, $K_c$, at the temperature considered, indicates that
>
> (**A**) the reaction has a very high yield;
> (**B**) both reagents were completely consumed.

#### Answer

> (**B**)

#### My thoughts

In my point of view, the higher the equilibrium constant, the more extensive the direct reaction is. Thus the conversion of reagents into products of the reaction is "bigger", so the yield of the direct reaction has to be very high. With that, my answer was (**A**).

1. Can we assume both reagents were completely consumed just by analysing the magnitude of the equilibrium constant or can still exist equilibrium even though the magnitude of the constant is so elevated?
2. Having in mind your chemistry knowledge, what answer do you think it's the "most correct"?

Comment: It really is a coin flip. Note that to get (B) you'd have to start off with $\ce{CO2}$. There is no other way to get an exactly stoichiometric mixture of $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{O2}$. But I'd say that (A) is always correct and therefore the better answer.

Comment: @MaxW thanks for answering. I'm sorry but I don't understand why I would have to start off with CO2. Could you explain, please?

Comment: It is a poor question. Raise your objection politely once and let it go. All in all it isn't worth getting into a brouhaha with your teacher over this.

Comment: I'm having dificulties understanding why couldn't I start with CO and O2 and getting these two to completly be consumed... Can you help me please?

Comment: In order for "both reagents" to be "completly consumed", you'd have to have **exactly** a 2:1 ration of carbon monoxide to oxygen molecules. Let's say that there was exactly one mole of  carbon monoxide. You'd have to have **exactly** two moles of oxygen. There isn't any way to really do that. But if you started with pure $\ce{CO2}$, then due to the reverse reaction the carbon monoxide and the oxygen would be in exactly a 2:1 ratio.